# Why doesn't Unity retain my Compiz settings?

Tags: unity, compiz

I installed CompizConfig Settings Manager in Ubuntu 11.10. Changes made to settings (for example key bindings) work perfectly, but the changes are not applied when I reboot. I have to run `compiz --replace` to re-enable my key bindings.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up adding `unity --replace` to my startup applications and that did the job.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be automatic, I had the same problem what I did is create a txt file, I wrote in it unity --replace . Saved it and made it executable and